# I am facing problem in understanding math symbol?

Tags: notation, vectors, normed-spaces

I am trying to understand a symbol and facing difficulties to solve it!!

$$\|F\|^2$$

where $F$ is vector (suppose $F = [1 \; 2 \; 3]$). How to solve this ? I know following symbol only

$$\|F\| = \left( (1)^2 + (2)^2 + (3)^2 \right)^{1/2}$$

Kindly help me out as I have never seen the said symbol before.

Also can some one tell me the difference between $\|F\|^2$ and $\|F\|_2$?

Comment: For future reference, you might find this link handy when it comes to formatting your posts -- https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

$\|F\|^2$ ultimately would mean the same thing as $\|F\|$, just now squared - so it's simpler than you think. If $\|F\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm as mentioned in your post for the vector $F = [ 1 \; 2 \; 3 ]$, then

$$\|F\| = \sqrt{1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2}$$

and thus

$$\|F\|^2 = \left(\sqrt{1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2}\right)^2 = 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2$$

Of course, $\|F\|$ might mean a different norm than this Euclidean norm, but usually it is well-understood what norm is meant whenever the symbol is used. The Euclidean norm is often given the shorthand $\|F\|_2$ to help make it more clear which norm we're referring to.

Similar related norms exist, anecdotally. For example, let $p$ be a real number greater than or equal to $1$, and let $F$ denote the vector $[ x_1 \; \cdots \; x_n ]$. Then we can define the $p$ norm $\|\cdot \|_p$ by

$$\|F\|_p = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p \right)^{1/p}$$

with the Euclidean norm having the special case of $p=2$. If you haven't been introduced to other types of norms yet, though, don't worry so much about all this "different kinds of norms" stuff, it'll become clearer in due time.

Comment: thanks a lot !! It means lot !